# Adding 10 second pause to CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**I'm familiarizing myself with CSS animation, and have been attempting to switch content in/out with a fade transition.**

[Link to Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/androbaut/pen/PJGoJX)

**Here's where I'm looking for advice**: I'm trying to make each text element remain for 10 seconds before switching to the next, instead of the 1 second interval I've got right now. I've tried changing the animation-delay settings, but that hasn't had the effect I anticipated.

**Here's the code:**

**HTML**

```
<h1>Here's some stuff</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class='whoiam'>
    <h2>Florb</h2>
    <h2>Dongus</h2>
    <h2>Bizzlebrop</h2>
    <h2>Yoindle</h2><!--This value will be the last to show on loop. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
overflow:hidden;
height:48px;
}

.whoiam{
-webkit-animation: move;
        animation: move;
position:relative;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
        animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: step-start;
        animation-timing-function: step-start;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-delay: 1s;
}
h2{ height:48px;margin:0;padding:0}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
0% { margin-top: 0em; }
25% { margin-top: -48px; }
50% {margin-top: -96px;}
75% {margin-top: -144px; }
100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
@keyframes move {
0% { margin-top: 0em; }
25% { margin-top: -48px; }
50% {margin-top: -96px;}
75% {margin-top: -144px; }
100% {margin-top: 0;}
}

h2{
-webkit-animation: fade;
        animation: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
50% { opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
100% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
}

@keyframes fade {
0% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
50% { opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
100% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
}
```

Any advice/suggestions/constructive criticism is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

```
.whoiam { 
    animation-duration: 40s; /* 4 x 10s */
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

h2 { animation-duration: 10s; }

@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;} 
    10% {opacity: 1;} 
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

This is the full code ([the pen](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/eGdmrM)) :

```css
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:48px;
}
.whoiam{
    -webkit-animation: move;
            animation: move;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
            animation-duration: 40s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: step-start;
            animation-timing-function: step-start;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
            animation-delay: 10s;
}
h2{ height:48px;margin:0;padding:0}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% { margin-top: 0em; }
    25% { margin-top: -48px; }
    50% {margin-top: -96px;}
    75% {margin-top: -144px; }
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
@keyframes move {
    0% { margin-top: 0em; }
    25% { margin-top: -48px; }
    50% {margin-top: -96px;}
    75% {margin-top: -144px; }
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}

h2{
    -webkit-animation: fade;
            animation: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
            animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
    10% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
    100% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
    10% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=110); }
    100% { opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
}
```

```html
<h1>Here's some stuff</h1>
<div id="container">
<div class='whoiam'>
  <h2>Florb</h2>
  <h2>Dongus</h2>
  <h2>Bizzlebrop</h2>
  <h2>Yoindle</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share an example, this shed some light on what I was doing wrong.